# How to use a thread to run another JFrame while the main is still running

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe

I have a jframe i want to display while my main frame is running. i want to pause my main code, until the user does the necessary actions on the other frame. I've read a lot of solutions but i need to see it done for my code to understand and grasp it fully. i do not want to use jdialog like I've seen listed as an answer before. My main goal is to understand better threading so that i can use what i learn in different cases.

With the code I've created, when running the thread, only just the frame loads, none of the other features are there on the frame. (the frame is simple it has a label, a list the user selects from, and a button to basically return the chosen list value.) its like the thread is cut off from completing or something.

here is my class calling the screen:

```
public class myThread implements Runnable {

    String result = null;

    public void run() {
        MessageScreen ms = new MessageScreen();
        ms.setVisible(true);
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String AS) {
        result = AS;
    }

}
```

in my main code, a method is called that is returning a String[] value, with this method at some point i have the following code calling the new thread to get the value necessary to return in the original main method:

```
    myThread mt = new myThread();
    Thread t = new Thread(mt);
    t.start();
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    myreturn = new String[] {"true", mt.getResult()};
```

without listing the whole code for the second frame, when the user presses the button, and at the end of the listener tied to the button press the i want to close the frame and return a string that was selected from the list:

```
jf.dispose();
myt.setResult(AdminSelection);
```

in the frame class, i have the following instance variables declared:

```
String AdminSelection = null;
myThread myt;
```

i hope this is enough information for someone to help me out and understand whats gone wrong here.

Comment: Start learning here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: You should put the idea that frames "run" out of your head. Frames respond to events. Normally, when you see something happening in a frame, if it's not being driven by user input (e.g., by mouse clicks or keyboard presses), then it's probably being driven by _[timer events](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)_.

Comment: In the Swing framework, events are delivered by the framework's Event Dispatch Thread (a.k.a., the EDT) calling your registered handler methods. Most of Swing's methods are _not_ thread-safe, and they should not ever be called by any other thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `join()` waits until the end of the `run()` method, when you do `t.join()`, your thread is already or almost ended. This is because in your `run()` method there is nothing that blocks the thread until the user has clicked the confirm button. And is better like this!

There is no sense to create a thread here, you should use a callback, or more generally in Java, a listener. You can take a look at [Creating Custom Listeners](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners).

---

But, especially if you want to pause your main code, you should use a (modal) `JDialog` which is made for this! Don't try to block the UI by yourself, you could block the UI thread (handled by Swing/AWT) by mistake. Creating a `JDialog` is better because everything is already made for this usage on the UI thread.

Also, you must know that create a `Thread` is really long, use a `Thread` when you really need it.

Comment: can you explain the join at the end of the run method again in a little more detail? the reason im am trying to use a thread is because i have a jframe with a button, and under certain conditions the listener tied to the button will then call this new messagescreen to return a value to back to the listener. my problem was the listener code wasn't pausing for the message screen to return the value selected by the user. i wanted to see how i could do a thread with my code to pause the listener and wait until done with the other screen, but i guess i will just use a jdialog

Comment: Yes, in your case the JDialog is perfect.
About the join method, this method wait until the end of the thread. The end of the thread is basically when the run method is ended.
So, if in your run method there is no time expensive code (big work job, sleep...), the thread end up really quickly. It's your case, creating a window and show it up is not a blocking operation (that's why the thread is totally useless).

Comment: IMO this answer would be better if the part before 'use a dialog' was deleted.